# Error in loading model in Sample Reflective Editor

Tags: emf, model-driven, ecore, model-driven-development

I can open my .model file in `Exeed Editor`. But when I want to open it in `Sample Reflective Editor` it has below errors. What should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the metamodel is registered both through a plugin and manually.